# Having trouble translating code from Haskell to SML

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, sml, category-theory, catamorphism

I am trying to translate the following piece of code from SML to haskell but I'm having a bit of trouble.

```
type List_alg x u = (u, x->u->u)
list_cata :: List_alg x u -> [x] -> u list_cata (a,f) = cata where
  cata[] =a
  cata (x:l) = f x (cata l)
```

Here is what I've tried:

```
type ('a, 'b) List_alg = 'b * ('a -> 'b -> 'b)

fun list_cata (((a, f): List_alg), (l: 'a list)): 'b = 
  case l of
       [] => a
     | x::xs => f x (list_cata ((a,f), xs))
```

I get the error `Error: type constructor List_alg given 0 arguments, wants 2`
but I'm not sure what is wrong/how to fix that. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The error simply says that `List_alg` is not a type, but `('a, 'b) List_alg` is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`List_alg` is a type constructor that expects two arguments, but you used it without any arguments on the third line. Try changing it to `('a, 'b) List_alg` as in

```ml
fun list_cata (((a, f): ('a, 'b) List_alg), (l: 'a list)): 'b =
```

Notice that your Haskell implementation also passes `x` and `u` after `List_alg`

Comment: thank you! I'm just learning functional programming. I was wondering what is the proper way to return a function in SML similar to that in haskell? In the Haskell code there is the line ```cata where cata ...```

Comment: @dtran you can just return functions the same way, not sure what the problem is. In any case, that's a separate question make another post with an example maybe?